# Logstash-forwarder stopping after running for a few days

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash on one server and logstash-forwarder on another server to send the log files. The server that is sending the files via logstash-forwarder is processing a good amount of logs ( ~ 400,000 every 10 minutes). After about 2 days of running logstash-forwarder stops working and I have to restart it. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do it have any error message?

Comment: Nope, no error message. Just stops doing its job.

Comment: OS?  If you are running on linux, can you run strace -p <pid> and see what it is doing? (strace lists system calls it's making), might help someone diagnose the problem.

Comment: Yeah I'm on linux. strace only outputs "wait4(-1," and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

This is caused mostly by the log rotate of the log files you are forwarding. 
here is the same example that happened to me: the syslog is recoding events and then stops at 00:01,

```
Oct 28 23:59:37 vhcdm5a logstash-forwarder[21246]: 2014/10/28 23:59:37.086385 Registrar received 6 events
Oct 28 23:59:44 vhcdm5a logstash-forwarder[21246]: 2014/10/28 23:59:44.586154 Registrar received 5 events
Oct 28 23:59:49 vhcdm5a logstash-forwarder[21246]: 2014/10/28 23:59:49.586503 Registrar received 3 events
Oct 28 23:59:54 vhcdm5a logstash-forwarder[21246]: 2014/10/28 23:59:54.586481 Registrar received 3 events
Oct 29 00:00:01 vhcdm5a CRON[23334]: (graphite) CMD (/home/graphite/scripts/execute_graphite_scripts.sh 1)
Oct 29 00:00:02 vhcdm5a logstash-forwarder[21246]: 2014/10/29 00:00:02.085533 Registrar received 3 events
Oct 29 00:01:01 vhcdm5a CRON[23787]: (graphite) CMD (/home/graphite/scripts/execute_graphite_scripts.sh 1)
Oct 29 00:02:01 vhcdm5a CRON[24338]: (graphite) CMD (/home/graphite/scripts/execute_graphite_scripts.sh 1)
Oct 29 00:03:01 vhcdm5a CRON[24794]: (graphite) CMD (/home/graphite/scripts/execute_graphite_scripts.sh 1)
Oct 29 00:04:01 vhcdm5a CRON[25260]: (graphite) CMD (/home/graphite/scripts/execute_graphite_scripts.sh 1)
Oct 29 00:05:01 vhcdm5a CRON[25721]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Oct 29 00:05:01 vhcdm5a CRON[25723]: (graphite) CMD (/home/graphite/scripts/execute_graphite_scripts.sh 1)
Oct 29 00:06:01 vhcdm5a CRON[26178]: (graphite) CMD (/home/graphite/scripts/execute_graphite_scripts.sh 1)
Oct 29 00:07:01 vhcdm5a CRON[26660]: (graphite) CMD (/home/graphite/scripts/execute_graphite_scripts.sh 1)
Oct 29 00:08:01 vhcdm5a CRON[27126]: (graphite) CMD (/home/graphite/scripts/execute_graphite_scripts.sh 1)
```

you can find out roughly when it stops

a) you can get it to forward the syslog to logstash / elastic search so it monitors it self and you can see where it stopped!

b) something like  `tail -1000 syslog.1 | grep logstash` will show you when it stopped parsing logs, then find the last event `grep -C 10 "00:00:02.085533" syslog.1` so you at least know when it stops.

In my case we do log rotate at 00:00:00 so it lines up pretty well. some of your options are:

1) put a job in to restart the forwarder every 12 hours or something.

2) ammend the logrotate policy so it rotates more frequently for example if you use log4j you can use `yyyy-MM-dd-a` to rotate every 12 hours.

you can read a little more of peoples trials and tribulations here
https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash-forwarder/issues/162